# How can I use a PHP variable inside an iframe?

Tags: php, html

I'm having this problem that I'm trying to use my `$test` variable inside my iframe in the `src` section and each time I try it fail and only a black border shows up.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9t5ItWlWyDg/';
    $parts = explode('=', $url);
$url2 = $parts[1];

$url3 = trim($url2,"?\/");
    echo $url3;

$youtube = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/';
$video = $url3;
$vars = '&loop=1&autoplay=1';

 $test = ($youtube . $video . $vars);
    echo $test;

?>
<br>

 <iframe width="420" height="345"
 src="<? $test ?>">
 </iframe>
```

Comment: try `<?php echo $test;?>` in your src="" bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use echo like:

1. `src="<? echo $test ?>">`

or

1. `src="<?=$test ?>">`